# Identifying sentences which contain a word, and displaying that word in a column using str.contains

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, substring, contains

I have a dataframe which contains sentences, I want to use str.contains to find out if the sentence contains the word, and then add the found word(s) in a column in the dataframe.
Eg: Input

```
dataset['sentence']
0    I am using a macbookpro and I like it.
1    I am using dell with windows OS and I love it.
        ........


   searchfor = '|'.join(searchfor)
   searchfor
 
0  windows|macbook|love


dataset['Match']=dataset['sentence'].str.contains(searchfor)
dataset['Matchcount']=dataset['sentence'].str.count(searchfor)

**Expected Output:**
    sentence                                             Match            Matched Word      Matchcount
    I am using a macbookpro and I like it.               True             macbook           1
    I am using dell with windows OS and I love it.       True             windows,love       2
```

How can I get the 'Matched word' in my output?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most efficient way, but this should do it:

```py
import re

regex = re.compile(searchfor)
dataset["MatchedWords"] = dataset.apply(lambda l: set(regex.findall(l["sentence"])), axis=1)
```

You could put the the set part in join/list if you want strings/a list instead.

EDIT : Does this minimal example give the expected result on your end?

```py
dataset = pandas.DataFrame({'sentence':["I am using a macbookpro and I like it.", "I am using dell with windows OS and I love it."]})
regex = re.compile("windows|macbook|love")
dataset["MatchedWords"] = dataset.apply(lambda l: set(regex.findall(l["sentence"])), axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi I use the following, 

regex = re.compile(searchfor)
dataset["MatchedWords"] = dataset.apply(lambda l: set(regex.findall(l["sentence"])), axis=1)

However, I get an empty {} list across all rows. Basically it tells me that no matches were found, am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Are the strings you are searching for more than just words? If they have special characters in them it might mess up the regex.
Is this at least working for the data from your example ?
[Moved code to the answer]
Does this minimal example give the expected result?

Comment: Yes they are 2-3 words together, like "communicable diseases", "social distancing". There are no special characters, I remove those in the processing of data. I have around 20+ search words, when I reduce the list to 3-5 words, the code above works, when I add all the words it gives me an empty list.

Comment: I'm at a loss then. I would try to pinpoint if a specific subset of those 20+ words is causing the issue (trying with both half separately, repeating with any of those halves that  displays the issue until I find a few words that might be causing an issue). Also, definitely unrelated to the issue but I would also ignore case by adding the re.IGNORECASE option to the re.compile call.

Answer (score 0):

I would maybe look at spaCy's pattern matching + NER to start. The pattern matching rules spacy provides are really powerful, especially when combined with their statistical NER models. You can even use the patterns you develop to create your own custom NER model. The doc returned by spaCy will give you match location information in the string you provide so you can pull it out and display it with the text you provided as input.

Adding REGEX entities to SpaCy's Matcher